# JS/jQuery Accessing iframe elements cross domain (but the js file is the same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page (different domain) with an external js file that lives on the same domain as an iframe that is also on the page... can this js file access contents in this iframe since they are sitting on the same domain? Or is that still not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter what domain the JS files are on, only the domain of the web pages / frames.

Here's an [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) on the same-origin policy for more detailed info.

Comment: Exactly. The browser doesn't care where the JS comes from; at the moment of execution, you have a piece of local code (running in your browser) trying to grab a page from a domain other than the current page.